# Reveal Image onClick

Tags: image

I am working on a project. How can I use Javascript to reveal a centered image when clicking inside a box without using a button?

Comment: You can use onclick on nearly every html element.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide some code?

Comment: You _can_ use onclick on nearly every html element, but you _should_ never use onclick on any html element; you should `addEventListener()` instead, because of [Separation of Concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) -- don't mix your M your V and your C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this you mean? I used javascript a little, but it works!!!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 50px; height: 50px;" onclick="xSignDisplayLetter()" id="one"></div>
    <br />
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 50px; height: 50px;" onclick="xSignDisplayLetterVerTwo()" id="two"></div>
    <br />
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 50px; height: 50px;" onclick="revealImg()" id="image"></div>
    <script>
    function revealImg() {
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png' alt='Image' style='width: 50px; height: 50px;' />"
    }
    function xSignDisplayLetter() {
        document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "<img src='https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/x-symbol_318-1407.jpg' alt='Image' style='width: 50px; height: 50px;' />"
    }
    function xSignDisplayLetterVerTwo() {
        document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "<img src='https://d3qdvvkm3r2z1i.cloudfront.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/6b9ffbf72458f4fd2d3cb995d92e8889/n/o/nope_newthumb.png' alt='Image' style='width: 50px; height: 50px;' />"
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you don't know javaScript a little, then there are js tutorials all over the web.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) is a good idea for short-term tutorials that teach you a lot, and is relatively fun to mess around with.

[CodeCademy](http://codecademy.com/) is a good long-term full code tutorial that will take a few weeks to learn but helps a million via your coding skill. You will need to sign up but it's free and saves all your work (code) when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You should load the image in your HTML and hide it using a CSS class like `hidden`. Then you will want to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to run a function when the image is clicked, which toggles the visibility of the image. The centering of the image can also be done using CSS.

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

blocks.forEach((block) => {
  block.addEventListener('click', () => toggleVisibility(block.querySelector('img')));
});

function toggleVisibility(el) {
  el.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.block {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <img src="https://www.placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <img src="https://www.placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <img src="https://www.placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: upvoted for _**not**_ using `onclick="something()"` but adding code as a stack-snippet here would be great.

Answer (score 0):

add an `onclick` attribute to your boxes that calls a function that shows a hidden image.

`<div onclick="showImages()"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

you can add onclick listener to div and in onclick function you can change div's class

```
<div class="redbox" id="box" onclick="showImage()"></div>

showImage(){
   var box =document.getelementbyid("box").
   box.classList.remove("redbox");
   box.classList.add("image");
}
```